# I dont know whats wrong with stdout in interactive task, testing system say that idleness-limit-exceeded occured

Tags: python, stdout

Interactor give lines with answers asked by programme on new line, but there is some problems with flush. It doesnt work on testing server, but on my computer all is okay

```
    from sys import stdin, stdout
    islier = False
    print('? 1')
    stdout.flush()
    t = int(stdin.read().rstrip('\n'))
    if t == 1:
        islier = True
    l = 1
    r = 100000
    while l != r:
        print('? ' + str((l + r) // 2))
        stdout.flush()
        t = int(stdin.read().rstrip('\n'))
        if islier:
            t = abs(t - 1)
        if t == 1:
            r = (l + r) // 2
        else:
            l = (l + r) // 2
    print('! ' + str((l + r) // 2))
```

Comment: Sounds like the testing server isn't emulating the stdout stream properly — assuming that's one of the "some problems" which you haven't specified.

Comment: Can you specify what the problems with flush are? Does the code hang or does flush raise an error? Could you also tell what the program is trying to accomplish?

Comment: Testing server dont say whats wrong, i think server cant get my request. I tried sys.stdout.write(), but it was awful too

Comment: By the way, if you are using `sys.stdout.flush()` for the print statement, you could use `print("hi", flush=True)`.

Comment: I tried it and it didnt work

Comment: Can you explain what error you are recieving? Is the code not printing? If that is true, the problem might not be with the flush. If it says that the system is idling to long, your way of reading the stdin might be the problem.

Comment: `read()` never returns until the input is completely closed, so it can return the entire contents of the stream all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might not be with the flush. On my machine, running `sys.stdin.read()` blocks the system, which might lead to an idleness-limit-exceeded error. Use `sys.stdin.readline()` as that will return the moment the user types in enter:

```py
t = int(stdin.readline().rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try it now and report to you about results

Comment: THANK YOU GOD WHAT CAN I DO FOR YOU?